# DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('String data, right truncation: length 6454 buffer 6452', '22001') [SQL: u'INSERT INTO

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc, pandas-to-sql

With the help of python3, pandas and pyodbc (version 4.0.24), we are tying to upload a data frame with a column "Review" with usually large amounts of text in it. In the middle of the upload process we get the below error:

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('String data, right truncation: length 6454 buffer 6452', '22001') [SQL: u'INSERT INTO
```

When uploading to the DB, using the if_exists="replace", and we also add dtypes to the column like this:

```
{'Review Links': VARCHAR(length=4000)})
```

Is there anything we can do?

Comment: The error you are getting is issued by the database. How does SQL Server define the column in the database table? I don't think that SQL Server is going to pay any attention to  the `dtype` of the column in the dataframe.

Comment: What version of pyodbc are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson We are using pyodbc version 4.0.24

Comment: @BoarGules using pandas we are using if_exists="replace" so it should be applying the dtypes as innitial setup? How should we define each of the types for the columns?